# Blank page trouble in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I want to perform CRUD operations so I have a PostController, a create_post page and I have set the route in web.php.

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('/posts/create_post');   //link to the create_post page inside posts forlder
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title'=>'required|max:255',
            'body'=>'required'
        ));
        $post= new Post;
        $post->title=$request->title;
        $post->body=$request->body;
        $post->save();
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**resources>views>posts>create_post.blade.php**
posts is the folder where the create_post view is saved.
I have only included the form part because there are no includes or partials errors.

```
                <h1>Create New Post</h1>
                <div class="form-area">  
        {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'posts/store')) }}
    <br style="clear:both">
                    <div class="form-group">
                                    {{Form::label('title', 'Title:')}}
                                    {{Form::text('title', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'name'=>'title'))}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('body', 'Body:')}}
                        {{Form::textarea('body', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'name'=>'body'))}}
                    </div>
            {{Form::submit('Post', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary pull-right', 'name'=>'submit'))}}
{{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
```

**routes>web.php**
Route::resource('/posts/create_post', 'PostController');

When ever I am running the **http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/create_post** link the page is blank but I have used the same template for Welcome, About and Contact pages and are working perfectly but these pages are stored in separate folder and have a seperate controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
return view('posts.create_post');
```